# Definitions of Prediction vs. Predictor

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models

I am writing an article which includes discussion of the MMSE estimator of the posterior predictive distribution. Since I use this term quite frequently, I was considering referring to this estimator as the prediction, however, I am thinking that the prediction connotes an estimate rather than an estimator:

For the difference between the two, wikipedia states: In statistics, an estimator is a rule for calculating an estimate of a given quantity based on observed data: thus the rule and its result (the estimate) are distinguished.

On the other hand, I considered using the word predictor, however, this word seems to connote a variable that is used to help predict another variable, not an estimation function.

Any suggestions on which term (prediction/predictor) is more reasonable to use to denote such response estimators?

Answer (score 2):

The prediction is the estimate coming *from* the MMSE estimator. A predictor, as you point out, is a variable used in coming up with the prediction. The latter is **not** synonymous with prediction.

To talk about a prediction is to talk about the 'expected value of a new observation [given the specific inputs]'. This is equivalent to both the MMSE estimate and mean of the posterior predictive. This is a result of
$$
\begin{align}
E_y[y \mid x]  &= \int_\text{support of y} y f(y \mid x) dy \\
&=\underset{m}{\text{argmin}} \int_\text{support of y} |y - m|^2 f(y \mid x) dy \\
& = \underset{m}{\text{argmin}}\int_\text{support of y} \text{MSE}(y,m) f(y \mid x) dy \\
& = \underset{m}{\text{argmin}} \quad E_y[\text{ MSE}(y,m) \mid x] \\
& = \underset{}{\text{argmin}} \quad \text{expected MSE loss}
\end{align}
$$
where $f(y \mid x)$ is the posterior predictive. In this case $E_y[y \mid x]$ is the prediction, and any element of $x$ is a predictor (e.g., temperature, some demographic like age, sale price).

Comment: I guess that neither prediction nor predictor is appropriate as a shorthand for discussing the MMSE estimator of unobserved responses. I think I will refer back to it as the "response estimator" instead. Thanks!

Comment: @Clark, I think the prediction of the unobserved response is appropriate here. What makes you say otherwise?

Comment: I was thinking that prediction was akin to estimate (a fixed value, the result given the data), rather than estimator (the rule, a random variable with a distribution we can talk about). Possibly, the word prediction does not have as distinct a meaning as estimate/estimator, and could represent both?

Comment: p.s. - Definitely helpful to get your thoughts on this - decided to change to prediction.